# AOSP System Apps with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, gradle, android-soong

Does AOSP support Jetpack Compose for System Applications?

If so what changes have to be done in Android.bp file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. You can check the SystemUI code [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/Android.bp) and [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/compose/features/Android.bp).

The main dependencies that you'll need to add to your .bp file are:

```
 android_library/android_app {

     .........
     static_libs: [
        "PlatformComposeCore",
        "androidx.compose.runtime_runtime",
        "androidx.compose.material3_material3",
        "androidx.activity_activity-compose",
     ]
}
```